# Facebook Graph Object/Event post in new 4.0 SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I'm attempting to post a graph event like so with the new SDK:

```
   FBSDKAccessToken *token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
    FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];


    action[@"event"] = @"http://samples.ogp.me/680289198752391";

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/friendlish:add" parameters:action tokenString:token.tokenString version:@"v2.3" HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//    
   [connection addRequest:request completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                        if(error)
                            NSLog(@"%@", error);
                        else
                            NSLog(@"%@", result);

                    }];

    [connection start];
```

All works fine, and it posts -- but when I try actually changing up the example to something custom like this:

```
 NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *action = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
    NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *event = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
    event[@"og:title"] = @"My Event";
    event[@"og:type"] = @"friendlish:event";
    event[@"og:url"] = @"http://www.facebook.com";
    event[@"og:description"]  = @"Yaba daba doo";
    event[@"og:image"] = @"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png";
    action[@"event"] = event;
```

I get a first error in console before the connection NSLogs are called:

> Unsupported FBSDKGraphRequest attachment:{
>       data =     {
>       };
>       "fbsdk:create_object" = 1;
>       "og:description" = "Yaba daba doo";
>       "og:image" = "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png";
>       "og:title" = "My Event";
>       "og:type" = "friendlish:event";
>       "og:url" = "http://www.facebook.com"; }, skipping.

Then the error from the connection method NSLog:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"
>   UserInfo=0x174077080 {NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x17445f920 "unsupported URL"}

Comment: I am facing same issue. Have you found any thing ?

Comment: @SolidSoft Did you got any solution?? Please share here

Comment: @jalakpatel  Yes, In my case, FB id was wrong..

Comment: @SolidSoft ohh rest whole code was same as above?

Comment: @jalakpatel insted of "me/videos" use as "/{user-id}/videos" You will get user-id by sign in with facebook.

Comment: @jalakpatel https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/

Comment: @SolidSoft I have updated "/{user-id}/videos" still throws same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99940/discussion-between-jalak-patel-and-solid-soft).